# Autofact not respecting InstancePerRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

I'm using Autofac on an MVC project with Web API.

I'm registering all controllers:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(assembly);
builder.RegisterApiControllers(assembly);
```

and

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

I'm also using OWIN, and I'm registering a `UserManager` per OWIN request:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.GetService<UserManager>());
```

The `UserManager` needs an instance of `DbContext`, which is configured to be instantiated once per request:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>()
       .AsSelf()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Here is the problem:

When accessing a Web API controller, a`DbContext` is created to satisfy the `CreatePerOwinContext` call.
Then, in my controller, I inject another `DbContext`, and I expected the instance injected in the controller to be the same created in the `CreatePerOwinContext` call, **but it is not**!
If I access an MVC controller, everything works as expected.

I think Autofac is using two different resolvers, and not sharing instances between them.
How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I might suggest adding a couple OWIN tags to the question & title to get more visibility.